# When inputting data via a form, how do I access the foreign key and change it to the ID of the object I'm inserting the data into? (LARAVEL 7)

Tags: php, laravel, web, controller

when I send a form to the store function in my QuestionController, I have a problem. The problem is, I can submit the question title to my database, but the database is relational and the foreign_key of the question table is questionnaire_id. Every time I submit the form, I get an error where the questionnaire_id is null.

I'm wording this incorrectly but I don't know the proper terms and such because I'm new.

Basically, how do I allow my user to submit data to a relational database?

Here's my models with the relations:

Questionnaires:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questionnaire extends Model
{
//

public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function questions()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
}
```

Questions:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
protected $table = 'questions';

protected $fillable = ['question'];

public function questionnaire()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\Questionnaire::class);
}

public function answers()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Answer::class);
}
}
```

And here's my store function.

```
public function store(Questionnaire $questionnaire)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
      'question.question' => 'required',
      'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
    ]);

    //dd(request()->all());

    $question = $questionnaire->questions()->create($data['question']);
    $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);

    return redirect('/questionnaires'.$questionnaire->id);
}
```

Now, I'm using laravel 7, but I've been following a Laravel 6 tutorial and changing things as I go along (for example using laravelcollective on the forms), so the problem might be that. However, I've looked over the eloquent documentation for Laravel 7 and I can't find anything detailing how user input works with relational databases.

If you're good with Laravel 7 and know how to submit form data to a relational database, please help a brother out.

Thanks so much, stay safe.

Comment: Is questionnaire_id set in databse as nullable? I think, when you use create relationship method, that it will make in 2 steps. First create question without questionnaire_id and then update question with questionnaire_id.

Comment: @Autista_z it's not set to nullable, it's just $table->id(); in the Questionnaires table.

Comment: Then you can try save method, no create. The difference is, that the save method acceept not array, but Eloquent object. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: And nullable I ment in questions table, not questionnaires. If there questionnaire_id is nullable.

Comment: @Autista_z I gave the save() method a try but I couldn't figure out what kind of array I need to input. I tried:                                                                                                                           $question = new Question;
        $question->question = $request->input('question');
        $question->save();

        $questionnaire->questions()->save($question); but i got an error saying save() needs an array.